# Observable operator for pulling out value for later

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm using observables with the RXJS library and have a situation where I want to pull out a value and use it at an unspecified time in the future that is not the next operator or the subscribe method.

I am currently passing the value through every operation until I need it. Something that looks like this:

```
obsveable$.pipe(
    ofType('example'),
    map((action) => [
        action, // <-- passing this through
        somethingElse
    ]),
    map(([action, other]) => [
        action, // <-- through again
        anotherThing
    ]),
    map(([action, other]) => {
        // finally use action
    }),
);
```

I could maybe try saving it to a local variable – something like this:

```
let action;
obsveable$.pipe(
    ofType('example'),
    map((_action) => action = _action),
    map((action) => action.somethingElse),
    map((other) => {
        // finally use action
    })
);
```

Both of these solutions are suboptimal. The first gets unwieldy when there are a lot of steps and the second is subject to possible order of operations issues (and it's not using the cool reactive approach).

What other options are there?

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what do you want to acheive, I think maybe I understood what you mean but not quite.

Comment: The question is meant to be unopinionated. Any other solutions are of interest to me. @OphirBushinsky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a *closure* this way:

```
obsveable$.pipe(
    ofType('example'),
    mergeMap(action => 
        Observable.of(somethingElse)
            .pipe(
                map(other => anotherThing), 
                map(other => { 
                    // use action
                })
            )
    )
);
```